# Write specific API data to JSON file

Tags: json, node.js, giphy-api

I want to be able to only save specific data from the output of the API...

```
function getGiph() {
    giphy.search({
        q: 'pratt',
    }, function (err, res) {
        var gif = res.data;
        for (var i = 0; i < gif.length; i++) {
            var embed = gif[i].embed_url;
            fs.writeFile('./apidata.json', JSON.stringify(embed, undefined, 1), function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log('saved');
            });
        }
    });
}
```

This is my code, when I `console.log(embed);` it outputs only the embed_urls of the API in the terminal just like I want, but when I write to the JSON it outputs `"https://giphy.com/embed/XqOCxN1WpEzja"MsM0""` and that is all...

If I replace `'embed'` with `'gif'` in the `fs.writeFile()`, then of course it writes the entire API data to the JSON.

I have tried `JSON.stringify(gif, undefined, 1)`,
`JSON.stringify(embed, undefined, 1)`.

I honestly searched and searched I hardly ever ask questions because I almost always find a solution but this one has me, I am pretty new to all this as well.

Comment: What is `embed`? An object? An array? What type is it?

Comment: `embed` is my variable that I stuffed my data into from the `for` loop, finding anything that says `embed_url` and logging it. 

I figured out the issue.. What was happening is that using the `fs.writeFile()` I was creating a new file every time the loop happened, and writing to it, I needed to use `fs.appendFile()` so that it creates the file and then adds to the file instead of creating a new file every time.

Comment: Congratulations!